# Call a function to Parse Json from a view controller to other view

Tags: json, swift, function

I would to call a function from a view Controller in other view controller. This function will parse json and put the data into an Array that is global in a struct, the problem is that if I put the function in ViewDidAppear it will make a big number of requests to the web service, If I put the function in ViewDidLoad it will no download data, this is my function that I would to call

```
@objc func pazienti(completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let endpoint = MyStruct.endpointpazienti()
    ArrayGlobale.listapazienti.removeAll()
    guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        let error = BackendError.urlError(reason: "Could not construct URL")
        completionHandler()
        //
        return
    }
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        guard data != nil else {
            //self.updateUserInterface()
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            completionHandler()
            return
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            completionHandler()
            return
        }

        //            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        //            do {
        //                let todos = try decoder.decode([MyStruct].self, from: responseData)
        //                completionHandler(todos, nil)
        //            } catch {
        //                print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
        //                print(error)
        //                completionHandler(nil, error)
        //            }
        do
        {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String:Any]] ?? []
            print(json)
            for x in json
            {
                print(x["nome"]!)
                 ArrayGlobale.listapazienti.append(ListaPazienti(nome: x["nome"] as! String, cognome: x["cognome"] as! String, id : x["id"] as! String, data : x["data"] as! String, sesso : x["sesso"] as! String))

                //print(ArrayGlobale.listapazienti)
                //sleep(4)
            }

        }catch
        {

        }
    }
    task.resume()
    ArrayGlobale.action = completionHandler

}
```

to call this function is self.pazienti { }
but I try to make an extends class with a global function and this will make some requests that block the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You show us none of the code that would cause the problem. If you go for `viewDidAppear` you might have to introduce some state in order to know wether the request is already in progress (and not schedule another `dataTask` if it is). On the other hand your `viewDidLoad` should do what you require, it should be called just once.

It is however very probably not just a bad, but a *really* bad idea to store your completionHandler in some kind of global variable unless there is *really* no other solution for it. As far as I can see from the design of your `func pazienti` it seems to be located inside the "wrong" object. However you provide to little code to really judge this. Please add at least your callback-code to the question so I can amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you sould make a singleton class and place your method inside that singleton class. then you can call that method as

```
yourclass.sigleton.pazienti()
```